# prettyPhoto not working, no errors in console

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

Here is the code in my `<head>`:

```
<!-- Pretty Photo -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="prettyPhoto main stylesheet" charset="utf-8" />
<script src="/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Here is the image I am trying to load into the viewer.

```
<div class="altImage">
    <a href="http://scoutsamerica.com/uploads/485604_10201093620571706_1239548317_n_716437.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto">
        <img src="http://scoutsamerica.com/uploads/485604_10201093620571706_1239548317_n_716437.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
```

I've dont this dozens of times and cant figure out why its not working. Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't used this plugin, but dont you have to instantiate it somewhere? Like `$("img").prettyPhoto();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the documentation:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
});
</script>
```

Source: http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/prettyphoto-faqs/

You will also need to import the standard jQuery library to use jQuery plugins!

Comment: Oh, Hmm, I was looking at the demo source they were giving, I didn't see that in there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer by tymeJV was helpful, but still did not work.  This did, however:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
});

</script>
```